# an Issue when using a simple express request

Tags: node.js, express

I'm facing a stupid issue with Express and Nodejs,

I have a simple code which give the the ability to check if the headers exist or not in the request :

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    if (req.headers["x-caller-id"]) {
        res.status(200).send('found');
    } else {
        res.status(400).send('Header missing');    
    }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Everything works fine, but only when I use this request, it doesn't show what I'm looking for. this should show **found** but it doesn't

[image]

**I got a strange thing when I take off the referer or User-Agent header it works fine, but when I add both of them to the request, x-caller-id disappears**

Comment: Did you check your browser's web developer tools to verify that the network request did send that header?

Comment: It should work as you have it. Perhaps console out the header values the app is getting?

Comment: It's getting undefined

Comment: I got a strange thing when I take off the referer or User-Agent header it works fine, but when I add both of them to the request, x-caller-id disappears

Answer (score 0):

you can use `req.get('headername')` to get the header content.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    if (req.get("x-caller-id")) {
        res.status(200).send('found');
    } else {
        res.status(400).send('Header missing');    
    }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

source: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get

Comment: Thanks for your response ! but I have the same issue, have you tested it ?

Comment: what is the express version you are using?